# Objects positioning in SpriteKitScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

I am making this basic space shooting game but I can't get the x-coordinates of enemies right. Sometimes, they go out of the screen - or remain half inside at the edges. How can I fix this permanently regardless of which iPhone the app runs on?

here is the code for my positioning: (note that egg is name of my enemy. it is function I made for calling it every single time)

```
    func egg() {
        var egg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: list[Int(arc4random_uniform(6))])
        var min = self.size.width / 8
        var max = self.size.width 
        var point = UInt32(max - min)


        egg.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(point)), y: self.size.height)
        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-100, duration: 2)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        egg.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where things can be going sideways.

•  First, it looks like you're assuming the location of your scene's anchorPoint is at (0,0).  If it's not (the default .sks file now has an anchorPoint at (0.5,0.5), for instance), that could explain why your enemies never show up.  The first thing I would do is double-check the anchorPoint of my scene.

•  If you're adding these eggs to some other node besides the scene itself, then those eggs will "inherit" whatever translation, rotation, and scale that their parent node has.  In other words, if you add an egg at (20,20) to a node at (30,30), it will appear at (50,50).  Make sure the "context" of the eggs is what you expect.

•  Your "min" and "max" values seem a little odd.  The "min" looks like it is intended to be "indented" by 1/8th of the screen size on the left, but you aren't indenting it on the right.  Maybe that's what you intend, but if you intend them to have symmetrical behavior, then you'll want to back "max" off by an eighth, too.  Also, you're not adding that eighth back into the x value when you're determining the position, so this could stick an egg at x=0.  This would explain why your sprites are sometimes "half inside at the edge".

•  The size of your scene is not necessarily the screen dimensions.  This depends heavily on the "scaleMode" of your SKScene.  Check the documentation for more information on this, but briefly, the scaleMode tells SpriteKit how to render a scene that doesn't match its view in size or aspect ratio.  Does it stretch?  Does it crop?  Does it letterbox?  If you run a square 400x400 scene on a 1024x768 screen device, it has to have some way of knowing what you mean.  Does it draw that 400x400 in the middle of the screen and let stuff be seen "outside" that rect?  Or does it scale it up to fill the screen, cropping off the top and bottom?  Or does it scale it up to FIT the screen, allowing space above and below that is technically outside the scene's size?  Or does it scale it up and squash the scene to fit exactly?  If your scene isn't matching up exactly with your device's screen, this could explain why things are not playing nice and staying within visible bounds.